# Heap corruption: what happens if I don't close a (Q)file?

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

I open a (Q)file in a function but I forget to close it (because I wronged to write the code). What happens to the memory, the buffer and my informations?

Example (C++):

```
void myFunction(QString path)
{
    QFile file(path);
    file.open(...);

    if( _myWrongCondition_ )
    {
        informations = // do something
        writeInformationToFile(file,informations);
        file.close;
    }
}
```

Assume that I call this function in a `while`. Could this provoke an **heap corruption**?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, to forget to release a resource (such as a file) won't corrupt anything.

If the acquired resource is dynamically allocated memory simply it won't be released and you'll have a memory leak.

In this case if you omit to call the `close()` function nothing will happen at all because `file` is stack allocated, compiler will emit the code to call its destructor when it'll go out of scope (at the end of the function, in that code).

Comment: So if I read (and allocate) dynamically my information I could provoke memory corruption/leak? How can I avoid this?

Comment: Leak only (but memory and file descriptor), @Marco, this will not corrupt anything. If you allocate dynamically, you need to be extremely careful - nothing will automatically delete/clean up your stuff.

Comment: @MarcoCarletti simply don't forget to release what you acquire (so if you allocate memory with new you have to deallocate with delete, for example). Anyway you do not corrupt the stack or the heap, simply your program won't be able to use that resource until it'll be released.

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 3):

the destructor of QFile automatically closes it. So you won't have any memory corruption.

Comment: the close() also calls flush(). so you can be sure that your information will be written into file. and since you're creating the QFile object on the stack and not in the heap with "new", you don't need to worry about the memory.

Comment: The question is a bit odd, since in any case, what happens to your information that may or may not be allocated from the heap has nothing to do with whether file is closed or not. So it totally depends on what happens in code not included in your question.

Comment: I realize that I was not clear: what happens to my information (that I wrote into the file) if the program crashes before I close the file?

Comment: if you couldn't call flush() or close() than the things that you thought you wrote into file will be lost.

Comment: I read (again) the explaination about the stack and the heap from  [LearnCpp](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/) website: I realize (again) that I have a lot of things to remember and learn about C++ and memory management :)